# insertSections in tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

I want to insert some section after update but I have the same elements. How can I do it? I want to inset elements after last element. But have error.

My code

```
     [self.tableView beginUpdates];
     for (WallPost *wp in news) {
        if (!_tableDataSource.count || ![_tableDataSource containsObject:wp]) {
           [_tableDataSource insertObject:wp atIndex:_tableDataSource.count];
           [self.tableView insertSections:
               [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:
               _tableDataSource.count-1] 
               withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
        }
     }
     [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: What error r u getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what error you have exactly, but you are inserting `section` in the `tableView` in a `for` cycle. Instead, you should **add objects to your array**, and then **reload the sections** in the `tbaleView` using a set of index by the method `indexSetWithIndexesInRange`:

```
int count = 0;
for (WallPost *wp in news) {
    if (!_tableDataSource.count || ![_tableDataSource containsObject:wp]) {
        [_tableDataSource addObject:wp];
        count++;
    }
}

if(count > 0) {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(_tableDataSource.count-count, count) withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Just a report:

You don't need to use:

```
[_tableDataSource insertObject:wp atIndex:_tableDataSource.count];
```

because you are adding each time the object at the end..so prefer:

```
[_tableDataSource addObject:wp];
```

Comment: You should be using [self.tableView reloadSections:[Range] with Animation:Animation] to reload and the insert variant when you are adding additional sections.